# Problems installing openxlsx in RStudio

Tags: r, windows

I am a beginner with R and thus get stuck quite often. This time I am trying to export a database to Excel and thus tried to install `openxlsx` in the Rstudio's console. However, when I try the command

```
install.package("openxlsx")
```

it gives a message that Rtools should be previously installed which I already did but, for some reason, it goes unrecognized.

If I then type

```
library(openxlsx)
```

it gives the following message

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openxlsx’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘stringi’ In addition: Warning message: package ‘openxlsx’ was built under R version 4.3.1

I should also mention that the first R version that I installed was the 4.3.0 one. Now I downloaded the 4.3.1 version but my RStudio's console keeps identifying the R version 4.3.0.

Any suggestions? Thanks very much

I downloaded Rtools but, for some reason, the system does not recognize it

Comment: You seem to have multiple issues here. First, you need to get your R installation sorted out. If you have installed 4.3.1 correctly it should open automatically in RStudio, but you could try looking in "Tools->Global Options" to check. Second, the dependencies for `openxlsx` (such as `stringi`) should install automatically when you use the RStudio package manager pane. You can try `install.package("openxlsx", dependencies = TRUE)`. Or just keep installing the named missing packages until things work. Third: the message about Rtools is a warning, you don't need it unless installing from source.

Comment: correct command: `install.packages("openxlsx", dependencies = TRUE)`